# Is encoding of the query string needed?

Tags: http, url, browser, escaping

I see that Firefox does **NOT** encode an URL like `http://www.mysite.com/foo?bar=10/12/2010` when it sends a GET request. I know that URLs must be encoded, so I expected to see Firefox requesting `http://www.mysite.com/foo?bar=10%2F12%2F2010` (/ = %2F). I inspected the GET requests using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

**Should the query string in the url be escaped?**

I use [WebHarvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/index.php) and I see that when I ask it to download a page with the http directive, an URL like the one above is encoded like I expected (%2F instead of "/").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` is allowed in plain in the [query of a URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4):

```
query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
```

Anything else *must* be encoded using the [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1).

Comment: @cdarwin: Yes. While reserved characters *must* be encoded, unreserved characters *can* be encoded. So inside the query `/` is equivalent to `%2F`.

Comment: @Gumbo: so a site should always decode the query, right? I saw a site that doesn't do that

Comment: @cdarwin: No. You can encode the `/` as well as it is not a reserved character (unlike in the path where `/` is *not* equivalent to `%2F`).

Comment: @cdarwin: Yes. There is a [chapter on when to encode and decode](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.4) that describes this in more detail.

Comment: @Gumbo: well, the text at the link you gave tells when to decoded, but it doesn't says the URI must be decoded... it says the components must be parsed before the decoding (which implies that the decoding should occur, but it's not explicit)

Comment: @cdarwin: No, you’re right. It doesn’t say that the components *must* be decoded. But since the encoding of reserved characters is required and unreserved characters may be encoded as well, it implies that decoding is necessary to get the original information from the URI.

Answer (score 0):

If, by escaped, you mean URL-encoded, the short answer is yes.

There are a number of characters that are normally encoded during URL encoding but could normally appear in the URL without problem.

But sometimes the potential problems are not always obvious. I would recommend URL encoding query arguments, and decoding them from your site. After all, if you decode too many times, that should not cause any problem.

Comment: ok... but is seem really weird to see firefox not encoding the url! Why? I imagine that firefox does the right thing...

Comment: To address that specific case, you'd need to be more specific about exactly where the URL is coming from. I'm still a little vague on that.

Comment: you can type the url I wrote in the address bar and the behaviour is what I got. I think the answer of Gumbo is the correct one

Comment: I'm pretty certain that no browser encodes text this way. That's not the browser's job. The browser's job is simply to navigate to the URL you enter. If you enter an invalid URL, then something might not work. It wouldn't be the browser's fault.

Comment: You can type anything in the address bar. Try http://stackoverflow.com/?value=?&%nn. It's not valid but it remains unchanged (at least in my browser, Chrome). Again, it is not the job of the browser to modify addresses that you type in.

Comment: the browser does not apparently encode the url, but it does so when sending the http get request.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your problem.

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="bar" value="10/12/2010">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This displays the proper escape in address bar. Aren't you supplying this URL in an `<a>` element? Then you need to escape it in the HTML page **yourself** by either hardcoding it or utilizing the functions provided by the server side language.

Comment: What I described happens simply typing the URL in the address bar, or having a link <a href="http://www.mysite.com/foo?bar=10/12/2010">example url</a>

Comment: Then you need to escape it yourself.